How can someone find the source code of a base view in odoo to use its path to extend the view?
I'm trying to apply view inheritance to a base module view which is res.users . I found some examples that uses the same view for inheritance. But I still need the xpath to the specific child element.
Here is my code:
<odoo>
    <record id="res_users_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="model">res.users</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_users_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <notebook position="inside">
                <page string="Real Estate Properties">
                    <field name="property_ids">
                        <tree decoration-success="[('state', '=', 'sold')]">
                            <field name="name"/>
                            <field name="property_type_id"/>
                            <field name="postcode"/>
                            <field name="tag_ids"/>
                            <field name="bedrooms"/>
                            <field name="living_area"/>
                            <field name="expected_price"/>
                            <field name="selling_price"/>
                        </tree>
                    </field>
                </page>
            </notebook>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>

So I tried to search for the specific view xml file in github.com/odoo/odoo to find the specific path of the notebook but couldn't find it.

<notebook position="inside"> should be used to add a new "page" to the "notebook". The position "inside" is the default value, so you don't even need the position attribute at all. I'm not sure why your view id has a module name (estate) in it, but that could lead to overriding a view instead of creating a new extension view.

Excuse me for my mistakes, but I'm still learning Odoo development. To clarify my question, what I meant is, how can I get the exact position of a component or an element (I'm not sure what it's called) in another module that I want to modify?

Stupid answer incoming: understand XPath and it should be easy solving such things. A little hint for getting a full view as xml in odoo: use the debug mode, open a record in the form view and open "get view" in the debug menu. Embedded views of one2many fields aren't shown there, but it should help a lot. If you want to know which base or extension view is introducing a part of that full you, just search for it in the views. In the end some experience will help a lot, as usual.
